# Do Ember models in one-to-one relationship both need foreign keys?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember this is how a one-to-one relationships is declared:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  profile: DS.belongsTo('App.Profile')
});

App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});
```

Does this imply that Ember requires the foreign key to be on both models or is it sufficient (in the case we want the profile to belong to the user and the user to have one profile) to have the foreign key on the profile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the foreign key needs to be defined on *both* sides of the relationship.

See here fo a working example: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/50/edit

In the example I've defined that a post belongs to an author and a author belongs to a post, in real life this doesn't make much sense because an author would have been defined to have (written) many post's, but for the sake of the example it shows the concept.

Hope it helps.